# ActionScript 3: Zoom into movieclip while not scaling its childrens

Tags: actionscript-3, class, zooming, subclass, scaling

I've included a zoom functionality similar to the one explained at this website:
http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/zoom/

This works perfectly on my background image(a map, that is), but I want to keep the symbols on my map the same size while zooming in.

I probably could work this out by changing all the children's size when calling the zoom-function, but I am hoping there is some kind of easy code adapt in my children class to make the size of the instances unchangable. Is there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One crude way, so you don't have to calculate the symbols scale, would be to remove the symbols from the mapDisplayObject so they're no longer a child and instead put symbol placeholders. Then match each symbol's x and y to each place holder, using localToGlobal...

Comment: This sounds interesting. I will try to implement this code tomorrow. Probably I will have struggles, and need more help :)

Answer (score 0):

If your children are not scaled or skewed or rotated you can iterate all of them and set transformation matrix to 1/parentScale. Something like:

```
for each (var child:DisplayObject in parent) {
   var matrix:Matrix = child.transform.matrix;
   matrix.a = 1/parentScale;
   matrix.d = 1/parentScale;
   child.transform.matrix = marix;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my children are dynamically rotating, some of them :)